# Aligning equations with unequal amount of elements

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

        \begin{align*}
        \beta_{1t} &= \mu_1 + f_{11}\beta_{1,t-1} &+ f_{14}GDP_t + f_{15}FFR_t + f_{16}CPI_t + \eta_{1t}  \\
        \beta_{2t} &= \mu_{2,S_t} &+ f_{24}GDP_t + f_{25}FFR_t + f_{26}CPI_t + \eta_{2t} \\
        \beta_{3t} &= \mu_3 + f_{33}\beta_{3,t-1} &+ f_{34}GDP_t + f_{35}FFR_t + f_{36}CPI_t + \eta_{3t} \\
        GDP_t      &= &f_{44}GDP_{t-1} + \eta_{4t}  \\
        FFR_t      &= &f_{55}FFR_{t-1} + \eta_{5t}  \\
        CPI_t      &= &f_{66}CPI_{t-1} + \eta_{6t}  
        \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to have the variables on the 4th until 6th equation to be aligned in the same column as done in the first three equations (so GDP underneath the GDP column, FFR underneath the FFR column etc.) .

I am not sure how this is done when the equations do not have the same amount of elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\begin{document}
        \begin{alignat*}{8}
        \beta_{1t} &= \mu_1 + f_{11}\beta_{1,t-1} &{}+{}& f_{14}GDP_t 
                   &{}+{}& f_{15}FFR_t &{}+{}& f_{16}CPI_t &{}+{}& \eta_{1t}  \\
        \beta_{2t} &= \mu_{2,S_t} &{}+{}& f_{24}GDP_t &{}+{}& f_{25}FFR_t 
                   &{}+{}& f_{26}CPI_t &{}+{}& \eta_{2t} \\
        \beta_{3t} &= \mu_3 + f_{33}\beta_{3,t-1} &{}+{}& f_{34}GDP_t 
                   &{}+{}& f_{35}FFR_t &{}+{}& f_{36}CPI_t &{}+{}& \eta_{3t} \\
        GDP_t      &= && f_{44}GDP_{t-1} && &&&{}+{}& \eta_{4t}  \\
        FFR_t      &= && &&f_{55}FFR_{t-1}&& &{}+{}& \eta_{5t}  \\
        CPI_t      &= && && &&f_{66}CPI_{t-1} &{}+{}& \eta_{6t}  
        \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a way with a TABstack:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackaligngap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\alignCenterstack{
        \beta_{1t} &= \mu_1 + f_{11}\beta_{1,t-1} &+& 
                    f_{14}GDP_t &+& f_{15}FFR_t &+& f_{16}CPI_t &+& \eta_{1t}  \\
        \beta_{2t} &= \mu_{2,S_t} &+& f_{24}GDP_t &+& 
                    f_{25}FFR_t &+& f_{26}CPI_t &+& \eta_{2t} \\
        \beta_{3t} &= \mu_3 + f_{33}\beta_{3,t-1} &+& 
                    f_{34}GDP_t &+& f_{35}FFR_t &+& f_{36}CPI_t &+& \eta_{3t} \\
        GDP_t      &= && f_{44}GDP_{t-1} && &&&+& \eta_{4t}  \\
        FFR_t      &= && &&f_{55}FFR_{t-1}&& &+& \eta_{5t}  \\
        CPI_t      &= && && &&f_{66}CPI_{t-1} &+& \eta_{6t}  
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a standard `array`; the intercolumn space is set to zero; with `>{{}}c<{{}}` the spacing around the operation signs is set to the normal one.

I used a few `\multicolumn` command to avoid holes.

For multiletter variables it's better to use `\mathit`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{l}{#1}}
\begin{array}{ r *{6}{ >{{}}c<{{}} l } }
\beta_{1t}  &=& \mu_1 &+& f_{11}\beta_{1,t-1} &+& f_{14}\var{GDP}_t          &+& f_{15}\var{FFR}_t &+& f_{16}\var{CPI}_t &+& \eta_{1t}  \\
\beta_{2t}  &=& \mc{\mu_{2,S_t}}              &+& f_{24}\var{GDP}_t          &+& f_{25}\var{FFR}_t &+& f_{26}\var{CPI}_t &+& \eta_{2t} \\
\beta_{3t}  &=& \mu_3 &+& f_{33}\beta_{3,t-1} &+& f_{34}\var{GDP}_t          &+& f_{35}\var{FFR}_t &+& f_{36}\var{CPI}_t &+& \eta_{3t} \\
\var{GDP}_t &=&       & &                     & & \mc{f_{44}\var{GDP}_{t-1}}                       & &                   &+& \eta_{4t}  \\
\var{FFR}_t &=&       & &                     & & \mc{f_{55}\var{FFR}_{t-1}}                       & &                   &+& \eta_{5t}  \\
\var{CPI}_t &=&       & &                     & & \mc{f_{66}\var{CPI}_{t-1}}                       & &                   &+& \eta_{6t}  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, for this particular structure, the input can be simplified.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{ r *{3}{ >{{}}c<{{}} l } }
\beta_{1t}  &=& \mu_1 + f_{11}\beta_{1,t-1} &+& f_{14}\var{GDP}_t + f_{15}\var{FFR}_t + f_{16}\var{CPI}_t &+& \eta_{1t}  \\
\beta_{2t}  &=& \mu_{2,S_t}                 &+& f_{24}\var{GDP}_t + f_{25}\var{FFR}_t + f_{26}\var{CPI}_t &+& \eta_{2t} \\
\beta_{3t}  &=& \mu_3 + f_{33}\beta_{3,t-1} &+& f_{34}\var{GDP}_t + f_{35}\var{FFR}_t + f_{36}\var{CPI}_t &+& \eta_{3t} \\
\var{GDP}_t &=&                             & & f_{44}\var{GDP}_{t-1}                                     &+& \eta_{4t}  \\
\var{FFR}_t &=&                             & & f_{55}\var{FFR}_{t-1}                                     &+& \eta_{5t}  \\
\var{CPI}_t &=&                             & & f_{66}\var{CPI}_{t-1}                                     &+& \eta_{6t}  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant using `alignat` with only 4 columns, and some `mathrlap` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools, bm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{4}
         \beta_{1t} &= \mu_1 & + f_{11}\beta_{1,t-1} &{}+ f_{14}GDP_t & & + f_{15}FFR_t & & + f_{16}CPI_t + \eta_{1t} \\
         \beta_{2t} &= \mathrlap{\mu_{2,S_t}} & &{}+ f_{24}GDP_t & & + f_{25}FFR_t & & + f_{26}CPI_t + \eta_{2t} \\
         \beta_{3t} &= \mu_3 & + f_{33}\beta_{3,t-1} &{}+ f_{34}GDP_t & & + f_{35}FFR_t & & + f_{36}CPI_t + \eta_{3t} \\
         GDP_t &= & &\phantom{{}+{}} f_{44}\mathrlap{GDP_{t-1}+\eta_{4t}} \\
         FFR_t &= & & & & \phantom{{}+{}}f_{55}\mathrlap{FFR_{t-1} + \eta_{5t}} \\
         CPI_t &= & & & & & & \phantom{{}+{}} f_{66}CPI_{t-1} + \eta_{6t}
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]